# Vue.js problems with custom validation directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom validation directive in vue.js. Validator works fine while typing in textbox, but as soon as I call `this.$validator.validateAll()`, it passees validation, even it should not.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Validation code

```
//validiates email in database. if email is not same as initial and email is taken, it will fail validation
VeeValidate.Validator.extend('unique-email', {
    messages: {
        hr: (field, args) => {
            return "Some error message";
        }
    },
    validate: (value, args) => {
        var initialEmail = args[0];
        if (initialEmail === value) {
            return { valid: true }
        } else {
            return profileService.emailTaken(value).then((response) => {
                var emailTaken = response.data;
                return {valid:!emailTaken};
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Save button

```
 methods: {
    save: function() {
        this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
            //should not enter here, but it does
        });

    }
},
```

Html elemenent

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EMail" v-validate="'required|unique-email:'+ initialEmail" v-model="profile.EMail"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified the same issue. I'm not sure what the problem is. The issue appears to be discussed [here](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2), but it doesn't seem to be actually resolved.

I do have a workaround for you though. The `errorBag` property of $`validator` does appear to be set properly if there is a validation failure, so you can check it in your save method.

```
save: function() {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
        const err = this.$validator.getErrors();
        if (err.errors.length > 0)
            //failed validation
        else
            //passed validation
    });
}
```

Comment: for some reason i had to use `if (errors.errors.length > 0)`